Flaky behavior on custom MS Teams App installation and after in usage
I have a bot service that's already working on Slack, and sometimes work as expected on teams. But for some users, after installation the app doesn't show the icon and correct name.
When installation is successful, the app doesn't hit the API at all, and doesn't show the logs how to see some logs for it.

Could you please confirm if all the users for whom the bot is working and users for whom it is not working are using the same version? Is this a custom app for your organization or the bot is available on store?

Yes, all users are using the latest Teams mac version. I created another azure bot that's worked, but took almost 4 hours to work properly.

You can check console for any error logs.

may I'm missing something, but I don't found any place to see the logs for it. In slack way to much easy create and configure application

Could you please refer this doc for debugging - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp
